# Is it possible to release Transaction-log locks from within an active (massive data movement) stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, commit, sql-server-2016

**edited terminology for accuracy:**

We have large, daily flows of data within our data-mart.  Some of the largest, done with Stored procedures managed by SSIS, take several hours.  These long-running stored procedures are preventing the transaction-log from clearing (which compounds the issue because we have numerous SP's running at once, which are then all writing to the T-log with no truncate).  Eventually this breaks our database and we're forced to recover from the morning snapshot.

We have explored doing "sub"-commits within the SP, but as I understand it you can't fully release the transaction log within an active stored procedure, because it is itself a transaction.

Without refactoring our large SP's to run in batches, or something to that effect, is it possible to commit to the transaction log periodically within an active SP, so that we release the lock on the transaction log?

**edit / extension:**

Perhaps I was wrong above: 
Will committing intermittently within the SP allow the transaction-log to truncate?

Comment: Not sure where you heard this but a stored procedure is NOT a transaction. You absolutely can break a procedure into units to ease the pressure on the transaction log.

Comment: Sounds like your calling code must be opening a transaction

Comment: You both may be right.  But we're definitely being told that our long-running SP, which is doing large inserts or table creations (which are certainly transactions with the SP) are locking the transaction log.  We attempted to insert in batches each terminated by `commit` clauses but this was throwing warnings which broke our SSIS Job, and we weren't convinced it was releasing the Transaction log.

Comment: @MartinSmith; Ok I think we're filling the transaction log which prevents other jobs from doing anything as they're waiting for the largest open transaction (our SP) to complete so the log can be cleared.

Comment: The transaction log is getting filled may be because your recovery model is full. All DML operations will have a log entry in the transaction log. Partitioning the table on a rolling range could be of some help.

Comment: @Dheerendra, we are using "simple" recovery mode.

Comment: A long-running transaction might exist at the start of the log backup. In this case, freeing the space might require another log backup. Note that long-running transactions prevent log truncation under all recovery models, including the simple recovery model, under which the transaction log is generally truncated on each automatic checkpoint.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/logs/the-transaction-log-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Dheerendra.  We're on the same page.  The question then is: Will the transaction log truncate if my long-running transaction executes a `commit` intermittently within the SP?  We are frequently having long-running transactions which crash our db and we would like to truncate the transaction log from within the stored procedure.  Is this possible?

Comment: By default SQL Server uses auto commit transactions and each transaction commits after each statement. If you are finding this is not the case then presumably SSIS is wrapping it in a transaction. check the `TransactionOption` properties in your SSIS package

Comment: @MartinSmith, good point.  We checked and our `TransactionOption` is set to "Supported" meaning no new transaction is made in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will committing intermittently within the SP allow the transaction-log to truncate?

If the client starts a transaction, it's not *recommended* to COMMIT that transaction inside a stored procedure.  It's not *allowed* to exit the stored procedure with a different @@trancount than it was entered with.

The following pattern is *technically* allowed, although I have never seen it used in the real world:

```
use tempdb
if @@trancount > 0 rollback
go
drop table if exists T
create table T(id int identity)
go
create or alter procedure tranTest
as
begin

  insert into T default values

  commit transaction

  begin transaction

end
go

begin transaction 
exec tranTest
select * from T
rollback

go 5
```

It would be deeply confusing for client code to rollback a transaction and not have the stored procedure's work rolled back.

If the client doesn't start a transaction, you can have multiple transactions inside a stored procedure, but the smallest granularity for a transaction is a single DML statement.  So each INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE would be run in a single transaction.

The practical solutions to this are, in descending order of goodness:

1) Increase the storage available to the log file to accommodate the transactions.

2) Refactor the ETL to use shorter transactions, possibly readying data in stating tables and loading or switching it in in a single, final transaction

3) Refactor the ETL to run in smaller batches.

Comment: We have a fairly massive transaction log size available.  The issue is when we have a long running SP (12+ hours), all the other threads running also contribute to transaction log and we easily eclipse the Terabyte mark.  Regarding suggestion 3:  Can we do batches within the one SP.  This would be much easier than refactoring the SP to run in iterations from the outside.  If so, it would be very helpful if you gave a simplistic syntax demonstration of how this looks - our attempts caused high-severity warnings that broke the SP.

Comment: Comment was too long: continued:  Specifically, how do we commit after each batch within something like [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5636/optimize-large-sql-server-insert-update-and-delete-processes-by-using-batches/)?   This is our preferred solution as it allows us to make changes across the dozen offending large SP's only at the point of insert, instead of a larger refactor.

Comment: Unless the client or server code starts a transaction, SQL Server will commit after each DML statement.

Comment: Could you confirm that, if we do our insert in batches, each executed insert will be committed, even if the SP is cancelled, times-out, or otherwise fails (no completed insert instance will be rolled back)?  This is actually the behavior we want in this case.

Comment: Yes.  I can confirm that, unless the client has started a transaction (or set the session to implicit transactions), each completed INSERT statement will be committed.